# Cross-Platform Browser Communication Between Page and IFRAME (Same Domain)

Tags: iframe, cross-platform, cross-browser, cookies, communication

For a specialized purpose with Aweber regarding a newsletter subscription, I have a page loading a nested IFRAME inside, and both reside on the same domain. (Many other stackoverflow posts talk about different domains, but this question deals only with the same domain.) I need a cross-platform way (including browsers as old as the dawn of IE6) for the two to communicate.

For example, someone fills out name and email and clicks a checkbox, and the hidden IFRAME next to the checkbox sits in a setInterval() loop watching for that. When it receives notification, it grabs the name and email and does a form post.

I thought at first that I could just drop a cookie in the parent page, and then the IFRAME child could then sit in an interval watching for that cookie. But my tests show that this won't work. The cookie gets created -- but the IFRAME can't see it. So, I tried the meta-refresh technique in the IFRAME, and again it couldn't see that cookie for some reason.

The only solution I can come up with is that the parent page will take the checkbox click (we use jQuery) and do an AJAX data push to the server into a database. The IFRAME can then check on an interval back to the server via AJAX to see if the database value has changed, and react to it if so. But this seems like an over-engineered solution and I'm looking for an easier alternative that works cross-platform, even in earlier browsers from the timeframe of IE6 and forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's much more simple: In the `iframe`, you can access the `parent` variable, which contains the parent window. So you can use `parent.document` to find the form, read the values, etc.

Comment: I tested successfully on IE6, IE8, all FF, Safari 4.0.4, Opera 10.50, and Chrome 4.0.249.89. All okay. So this is the solution for me.